# CSS tricky column layout

Tags: css, layout

I have a two column layout, where in first column there is always one item per row and in second column there are any number of items. The problem in my example is that the sizes differ and float only works, if the first column item is higher than the ones in second column.
I know best would be to wrap the items of the right column into one container, but I cannot change the structure of the HTML, I only can do some CSS and/or JavaScript (including JQuery). But I would prefer a CSS only solution.
I also cannot set the height of the first column items statically, because the amount and height of the right column items is dynamic.

The expected result:
[image]

See JSFiddle for my current approach:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/uqh9uz5o/

Thanks,
Ingo

Comment: why is the question downvoted? I could not find any solution anywhere and its no simple you should do it for me question...

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the "other" items in another div with its own float.

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="label">2 label</div>
    <div class="wrapother">
        <div class="other">2_hallo1</div>
        <div class="other">2_hallo2</div>
        <div class="other">2_hallo3</div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapother {
    float:left; 
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly, I cannot change the structure of the HTML content (not add any nodes)